# Java distinct causing thread block

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

In short, a chain of `distinct().limit(3).forEach()` is causing my thread to get blocked which is causing unhealthy container. My service is running in ECS fargate.

```java
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@ToString
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestPojo {
    private String pojoId;

    private String score;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private boolean isRandomOrdered;
}


private List<TestPojo> randomizeOrder(final List<TestPojo> testObjects) {
    // Picking testObjects randomly only from top 25
    final int topLimit = Math.min(testObjects.size(), 25);
    final Set<TestPojo> newOrderedPojos = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    // First 2 position are fixed
    newOrderedPojos.add(testObjects.get(0)); // Validations are present in calling function to make sure that get(0) and get(1) don't throw out of bound error.
    newOrderedPojos.add(testObjects.get(1)); 
    new Random().ints(2, topLimit).distinct().limit(3)
         .forEach(i -> newOrderedPojos.add(testObjects.get(i).toBuilder()
                                               .isRandomOrdered(true)
                                               .build()));

    // Add remaining objects. Since this is a set only objects not already present will be inserted.
    newOrderedPojos.addAll(asins);

    return ImmutableList.copyOf(newOrderedPojos);
}
```

The above intermittently gets a thread block and causes the whole container to go unhealthy since it is blocking threads and thus health check fails.

```
11 Jul 2023 16:19:12,942 [33m[WARN][m   (abc-periodic-metrics-0) com.abc.xyz.bobcat.StuckThreadDetectingValve: Thread Bobcat-2 is detected as stuck as it has been blocked for 4442432 ms
com.abc.xyz.bobcat.StuckThreadDetectingValve$StuckThreadException: Check stacktrace to see where the thread is stuck
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:597)
    at java.util.HashSet.contains(HashSet.java:204)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(DistinctOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
    at java.util.Random$RandomIntsSpliterator.tryAdvance(Random.java:1029)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEachWithCancel(IntPipeline.java:162)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:188)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:427)
    at com.abc.service.xyz.randomizeAsinOrder(TestClass.java:123)
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue? I checked the javadoc for distinct and limit and foreach but non seem to indicate that they are thread un-safe or such a case could happen.

Comment: What framework do those annotations come from?  Can you duplicate this in a test harness outside of the container?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The annotations are from Lombok. The problem about reproducing this code is that it doesn't happen all the time. There are sudden spike in failure and then it goes away. Not able to understand what is causing this.

Comment: Also, is `randomizeOrder()` your exact method or did you make changes just for Stack Overflow?  (I"ll agree with aled: even if you need to loop 10,000,000 times, a [mcve] that reproduces this error at least once per run would be invaluable.)

Comment: More of less the exact method. Just removed a few branching (experimental branching) which decides whether we execute this code or not.

Comment: Right, "more or less" leaves a lot of room for error.  If the code above produces the error, fine, but please prove to us and yourself that the code above does produce the error by creating a full [mcve].

Comment: That's the whole problem. I have a test running every minute and since yesterday night this kind of failure only happened 3 ( in an 8hr period executing this code every minute). Not very helpful i know..

Looking more into insight if anyone can spot anything obviously wrong..

Comment: The only thing I see is that `TestPojo` is not threadsafe, and might be not the actual object you are testing with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254452/discussion-between-belphegor21-and-markspace).

Comment: how big/small is `testObjects`? I believe that if less than 5 elements, that code will have a hard time to find 3 distinct random numbers

Comment: testObjects generally is 80-90 elements but can be small as well. We make sure to not call this function we don't have at least 2 items. Won't the `Random.int(2, topLimit)` not generate any random numbers preventing the execution if topLimit is low?

Comment: if  `topLimit` is 4 (or 3) this stream will block! There is no way to generate 3 distinct numbers from integers between 2 and 3 (inclusive)

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that the thread is stuck in calculating the hash. Seems weird.

Comment: just tested it with `topLimit = 4` and got very similar [stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPrSH.png) - simplified test: `new Random().ints(2, topLimit).distinct().limit(3).forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: @user16320675 you are right. It blocks. the javadoc of limit() does't mention such behaviour. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `limit()` alone, but also includes `distinct()` - it is impossible to generate three (or more) distinct number if given a bunch of `2`s and `3`s

Comment: Posted an answer with findings. Individually no function in the problem. It is the combination of an infinite stream( from random) and using limit() which is causing it.

Comment: no, if you remove the `limit()` it will still block. Kind of obvious, how is `distinct()` expected to generate more distinct numbers as given? With `limit()` low enough, the stream can be terminated before all distinct numbers are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
new Random().ints(0, 2).distinct().limit(3).forEach(System.out::println); // Can only generate 0 and 1.
```

The above line of code blocks. However

```java
IntStream.of(0, 1).distinct().limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Doesn't block.

In the second example the size of stream is fixed thus `limit` knows that and doesn't block. However, in first example `Random.ints()` isn't fixed in length thus `limit` keeps on waiting and thus ends up blocking the thread.

Basically the issue come from an infinite stream generated from Random.ints(). Distinct will pass along unique elements from that infinite stream and then limit will pick the top n. But since there is no third unique value, distinct keeps on waiting and limit is not stopping it. In second case since the stream limit is known if we didn't get a 3rd unique value by the end of stream jvm stops the processing.

Comment: WRONG `distinct()` will **not** generate an infinite stream - it will try to, but it cannot generate more than the numbers given to it (in your example it is only getting `0`s and `1`s, so it will only be able to generate one `0` and one `1` (in same order as it got them) and must wait until it gets a different number, but `Random` will never provide a different one - `distinct()` will be stuck  - unless stopped by `limit()` || if you remove `limit()` from first code snippet it will still block

Comment: @user16320675 It isn't `distinct()` producing an infinite stream, it's `ints()`. The answer is admittedly confusingly worded, but it's clear enough where the infinite stream starts.

Comment: It's not blocked, it is spinning in `Random`. Terminology please.

Comment: @David sorry, not clear what your problem is with my comment? What you want to say?  What you wrote is exactly my point, I even emphasized it: "*`distinct()` will **not** generate an infinite stream*", but the answer is stating "*Distinct will generate an infinite stream*"

Comment: @user16320675 Yes, but immediately before that it says "the issue come from an infinite stream generated from Random.ints()" so while the next statement does make it a little unclear, it does indicate that the problem comes from Random.ints(). I was just pointing that out. I've edited Belphegor21's answer, hope that helps.